# Find and select the offset cell of the result

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

How to write the code in VBA?

I need the `Search` command button to search for the `E2` which contain date value in the `B:B` row which also contain date value and select the `OFFSET(0,1)` cell The result ?

I'm getting this error:

> Object variable or with block variable not set

This is the code I used:

```vb
Private Sub btngo_Click()
    Dim thedate As String
    Dim fromlist As Range

    thedate = Range("E2").Value
    fromlist = Range("B6:B370")

    fromlist.Find(what:=thedate, after:=Range("B5"), LookIn:=xlValue, _
       lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
       MatchCase:=False).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `Find()` is not making a match, and so it returns `Nothing` - you can't call `Select` on `Nothing`

Comment: 1) `fromlist = Range("B6:B370")` should be `Set fromlist = Range("B6:B370")` 2) `Set` a `Range` variable to the `Find` method then check if is `Nothing` to see if there are any match before you `Select` e.g. `Dim findList as Range`, `Set findList = fromlist.Find(what:=thedate, LookIn:=xlValue, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)`, `If Not findList Is Nothing Then [code for match found] Else [code for no match] End If`

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, `fromlist = Range("B6:B370")` needs to have SET in front of it.

`Set fromlist = Range("B6:B370")`

`fromlist` is a range, when you try and set that variable, it returns an object and therefore needs SET ... you need this at a minimum and that should eliminate the error you're seeing.

A tip though, you should do more work around your `.Find` approach.  Again, it returns an object and if nothing is found, you'll get an error.  You should check for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion helped me to find the code for what I want.

```
sub whatever()

Cells.Find(What:=Worksheets("main").Range("E2"),After:=ActiveCell, _
LookIn:=xlValues,LookAt:=xlWhole,SearchOrder:=xlByRows,SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=True,SearchFormat:=False).Offset(1, 0).Activate

End Sub
```

Without `Dim` and `Set` it works perfectly.